# Inner Product and Norms of vectors

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials, inner-products

Let $p_0$ and $p_1$ be the polynomials in $\mathbb P_2$ given below, and let the inner product for $\mathbb P_2$ be given by evaluation at points $-2, 0, 2$, so
$$ \langle p,q\rangle = p(−2)q(−2)+p(0)q(0)+p(2)q(2). $$
Find the inner product of $p_0$ and $p_1$ and the norms of $p_0$  and $p_1$. Use the square root symbol $\sqrt{}$ where needed to give an exact value for your answer.

$$p_0 = −2x+1,\\
p_1 = −2x^2+2x−2.$$

As I understood the inner product is basically the dot product, I would think the answer to the following would be

$$ \langle p_0, p1\rangle  = −6, \\ 
\|p_0\| = \sqrt 5 ,\\
\|p_1 \| = \sqrt 12 .$$

but I have seen that the answers are wrong.

Comment: You’ve gotten it the wrong way around: the dot product (which really only makes sense relative to some fixed basis) is an inner product, but there are many other inner products besides.

Answer (score 2):

First the inner product. Using the definition we find

$$\langle p_0,p_1\rangle = p_0(-2)p_1(-2) + p_0(0)p_1(0) + p_0(2)p_1(2) = \\ =5(-14) + 1(-2) + (-3)(-6)= -70 -2 +18 = -54 . $$

The norms are compited in the same way:

$$||p_0|| = \sqrt{\langle p_0,p_0\rangle} = \sqrt{5^2 + 1^2 + (-3)^2} = \sqrt{35} ,\\
||p_1|| = \sqrt{\langle p_1,p_1\rangle} =\sqrt{14^2 + (-2)^2 + (-6)^2} = \sqrt{236} .
$$

Comment: how did you get all these numbers?

Comment: Oh, sorry. I'm going to added. But I have just substituted $p_0$ and $p_1$ in each pont. Better?

Comment: i am still confused at how you have gotten the inner product

Comment: Well, in your question you said the inner product of two plynomials $p$ and $q$ was $$\langle p,q \rangle = p(-2)q(-2)+p(0)q(0)+p(2)q(2)$$. Now take $p=p_0$ and $q=p_1$. It follows the firts equality of my answer. Finally you have to substitute $p_0(-2),p_0(05 -2),\dots$ by their values. For example: $$p_0(-2)=-2(-2)+1 = 4+1. $$